# How can i ignore certain folders from being downloaded using wget?

Tags: linux, download, wget

I want to download all the folders with their subfolders and files on a webpage except on folder that is contained in a subfolder of that website. How can i do it using wget? For example:

Website: https://index.org

Folder1:

-Subfolder1

-Subfolder2

-Subfolder3

Folder2:

-Subfolder4

How can i download all of the files and subfolders from the Folder1 except all the files and subfolders of Subfolder1?

Answer (score 0):

From wget --help:

`-X,  --exclude-directories=LIST  list of excluded directories.`

Untested, but provided now to give an answer sooner for you:

`wget -r -X http://example.com/Folder1/subfolder1 http://example.com/`

Comment: Thank you for the reply sorry im late but i already tried that type of script. I want to download everything from this folder https://doc.lagout.org/Others/ except the folder MAME which contains i think old video games and is very large. Could you try and see if you can exclude it and a tip if i can say dont try it with that folder because its large im testing that script with this folder https://doc.lagout.org/science/ so i can exclude the folders ComputerScience and ArtificialIntelligence and just download the one pdf file but it downloads everything. Again thanks in advance.